# How can I get the controls closer to video in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm adding a video to my html page but the controls are far from the video as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpbL0.png) How can I get them closer together and remove the grey space in between?

My HTML:

```
<div class="sameline">
        <video height="500" width="800" controls>
            <source src="../videosrecords/Half Brothers.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.sameline {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
video{
    outline: 0px;
}
```

Comment: isn't it just that the video has a wider aspect ratio than your video component, and hence the bottom part is empty? If so then just reduce the height

Comment: It  is but I need it to have the same size. I'm starting a mp4 file sharing website so all videos need to have the same size. Can't I make it stretch a bit or something?

Comment: stretch the video? wouldn't that look really ugly? Maybe you could center the video inside the component though, like is common in video display (think black bars on wide-screen movies on an old TV)

Comment: Removing the height from the `video` element would be the first step I'd try

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN - : The Video Embed element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video), adding the `controls` attribute will display the browser's default video controls.

I don't think you will have control over the default controls' location or appearance.

However, you can create your own custom controls "using JavaScript and the HTMLMediaElement API".

For instructions on how to create custom controls, see the MDN article on [Creating a cross-browser video player](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/cross_browser_video_player).

FYI, here is your code playing a randomly chosen mp4 file.

```css
.sameline {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
video{
    outline: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sameline">
  <video height="500" width="800" controls>
            <source src="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
</div>
```